# Haskell - unpacking a list into a custom data type

Tags: haskell, types

Is it possible to unpack a list into a data type, without specific pattern matching?

for example

```
data MyType = MyType Int Int Int deriving Show
let l = [1, 2, 3]

func :: [Int] -> MyType
```

usage would be

```
λ: func l
λ: Mytype 1 2 3
```

What I am trying to achieve.*

I have a list of lists which I pulled in from a CSV file. Each of the lists is a list of type variables. I was hoping there would be a fast way of passing those type variables into the type without having to pattern match ten or more variables.

Comment: Does this work for you:`func xs = MyType (xs!!0) (xs!!1) (xs!!2)`? We're not using pattern matching to deconstruct the list.

Comment: Perhaps a good question is why do you want to do it differently? Pattern matching is a safe way to do this. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What to do, if the list has only one element ?

Comment: @MarceloZabani I have edited my question to give some insight into what I am trying to do.

Comment: The only straightforward way (i.e. not using Template Haskell) is to just pattern match or deconstruct the list: `func [a, b, c, d, e] = MyType a b c d e`. The reason is that you're trying to convert something with a *non-static* number of fields (unknown at compile time) to something with a *static* number of fields (known at compile time; your data constructor). That involves a lot of edge cases which the compiler simply can't figure out for you. Like I said, however, I'll bet there's a way to do this in a non-straightforward manner using existing power tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally think you should use the pattern matching....

However, you can use the info in this answer to convert a list to a tuple....

[How do I convert a list to a tuple in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921345/how-do-i-convert-a-list-to-a-tuple-in-haskell)

---

Then you can use the info in this answer to convert that tuple to params for your constructor

[Uncurry for n-ary functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24843224/uncurry-for-n-ary-functions)

It works, and is sort of intellectually clean, but it is a lot of work to avoid one line of pattern matching.